# ObjectChoiceField in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, drop-down-menu

In my application there is one `ObjectChoiceField` in `MainScreen`

i want to get `change Listner` of `ObjectChoiceField` after click on index 0.

i had already get click event of ObjectChoiceField after click on index grater than 1 and so on .. 
so how can i get instance click event after click on `ObjectChoiceField`  ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what you are asking for.

In your `FieldChangeListener.fieldChanged()` method, calling `ObjectChoiceField.getSelectedIndex()` tells you which index is currently selected.  You can look for index 0 from that.

If that is not what you need, then you need to clarify your question better.

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectChoiceField choiceField = new ObjectChoiceField();

public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {

    if(field.equals(choiceField))
    {
if(choiceField.getSelectedIndex==0)
{your Code}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value which the user have selected you can do by this way too

```
ObjectChoiceField choiceField = new ObjectChoiceField();

public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {

if(field.equals(choiceField))
{
 if(choiceField.getSelectedIndex==0)
  {
     int index = choiceField.getSelectedIndex();
     String s = (String) objectWeather.getChoice(index);
     Dialog.inform("selected value is"+s);
    }
 }
}
```